# Entity Framework Join

Tags: entity-framework, list, join

I try to do join with entity framework but I need to List my information after join my normal method like this:

```
public DataTable LoadAllAllowing()
{
    var resultList = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=. ; database=PersonnelTrackingSystem;Trusted_Connection=yes");
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT PA.personelId
                                                 ,[allowedDatesId]
                                                ,[allowedStartDate]
                                                 ,[allowedEndDate]
                                                 ,[allowReason]
                                                ,PI.personnelNumber
                                                ,PI.personnelName
                                                ,PI.personnelSurname
                                                FROM [PersonnelTrackingSystem].[dbo].[personnelAllowedDates] AS PA
                                                JOIN PersonnelInformation AS PI ON PI.personelId=PA.personelId", connection);
    da.Fill(resultList);
    return resultList;
}
```

How I can do this with entity framework? I did like this but it doesn't work

```
  public List<PersonnelInfoAndAllow> LoadAllAllowing()
    {
        PersonnelTrackingSystemEntities entity = new PersonnelTrackingSystemEntities();
        //var personnel = entity.personnelAllowedDates.ToList();
        var allows = (from allow in entity.personnelAllowedDates join personnel in entity.PersonnelInformation on allow.personelId equals personnel.personelId select new { personelId = personnel.personelId, personnelNumber = personnel.personnelNumber, personnelName = personnel.personnelName, personnelSurname = personnel.personnelSurname, allowedDatesId = allow.allowedDatesId, allowedStartDate = allow.allowedStartDate, allowedEndDate = allow.allowedEndDate, allowReason = allow.allowReason }).ToList();
        List<PersonnelInfoAndAllow> personnels = allows;
        return personnels;}
```

I write class like that :

`namespace personnelTrackingSystem
  {
    class PersonnelInfoAndAllow
    {
        public int personelId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime allowedStartDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime allowedEndDate { get; set; }
        public string allowReason { get; set; }
        public int allowedDatesId { get; set; }
        public string personnelNumber { get; set; }
        public string personnelName { get; set; }
        public string personnelSurname { get; set; }
  }
}`
But it doesn't work. How I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like:

```
from pa in db.personnelAllowedDates
join pi in db.PersonnelInformation on pa.personelId equals pi.personelId
select new AnObjectDefinedByYou
{
    PersonelId = pa.personelId,
    AllowedDatesId = pa.allowedDatesId,
    //...
    PersonnelNumber = pi.personnelNumber
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how I do this in my method? This query must be var and my method should return List that has this variable. But when I write ' List<personnelAllowedDates>' it has not PersonnelInformation informations.

Comment: @Mualla - You are very close. You should define a new class, like `AnObjectDefinedByYou`, that has properties both from `personnelAllowedDates` and `PersonnelInformation`; then your method should return a `List<AnObjectDefinedByYou>`.

Comment: Again it does't work because program said not suitable types.

Comment: @Mualla - In your query, use `select new PersonnelInfoAndAllow { personelId = personnel.personelId` etc.

Comment: :) finally it is okey . Again thank you so much . I'm grateful to you.